How to trasmit data using uart from stm32 NUCLEO-F746ZG to BBG(BeagleBone Green)?
Testing of the stm32 nucleo-f746zg board
This is a part of the code I'm using to test transmitting and receiving data between the following pins on the Nucleo board: PC_10, PC_11, PD_12, and PD_2. This code currently functions correctly.
    /*
      Pin PC_10 is configured as UART-TX (port CN8)
      Pin PC_11 is configured as UART-RX (port CN8)

      Pin PD_12 is configured as UART-TX (port CN7)
      Pin PD_2 is configured as UART-RX (port CN8)
     */
    char msg[15] = "Hello World!";
    char resc_msg;

    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1)
    {
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < strlen(msg); ++i) {
            status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, (uint8_t*) (msg + i), 1, 1000);
            if (status != HAL_OK) {
                printf("UART_Receive failed with status: %d\r\n", status);
                printf("[err] could not transmit Uart tx\r\n");
            }
            HAL_Delay(100);
            status = HAL_UART_Receive(&huart5, (uint8_t*) &resc_msg, 1, 1000);
            if (status != HAL_OK) {
                printf("UART_Receive failed with status: %d\r\n", status);
                printf("[err] could not receive Uart tx\r\n");
            }
            printf("%c", resc_msg);
        }

        printf("\r\n");
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */



Testing of the BeagleBone Green
#include "uart.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // uart initialize
        uart my_uart("/dev/ttyS1", uart::BAUD_9600, 'N', 8, 1, 1, 1);
        std::cout << "UART initialized successfully!" << std::endl;

        // setting gpio
        my_uart.setupGPIO(71, "in");
        //  my_uart.setupGPIO(72, "out");
        std::cout << "GPIO 71 set to input mode." << std::endl;
        //  std::cout << "GPIO 72 set to output mode." << std::endl;

        // data that I want to send
//      std::string message = "Hello, World!";
        while (true) {
            int value;
            if (my_uart.readGPIO(71, value)) {
                std::cout << "GPIO 71 value read: " << value << std::endl;
                if (value == 1) {
                    std::string receivedData;
                    ssize_t bytesRead = my_uart.readData(receivedData, 1024);

                    if (bytesRead > 0) {
                        std::cout << "Received data: " << receivedData << std::endl;
                    } 
                    else {
                        std::cerr << "Failed to read data from UART." << std::endl;
                    }

                //  std::cout << "GPIO is high. Sending message: " << message << std::endl;
                //  ssize_t bytesWritten =  my_uart.writeData(message);
                //  std::cout << "Bytes sent: " << bytesWritten << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Failed to read GPIO 71 value." << std::endl;
            }

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

The Problem
Both code snippets work independently, but I'm having trouble sending data from the Nucleo F746ZG to the BeagleBone Green. I want huart4 on the Nucleo to transmit "Hello World!" to the BeagleBone Green's gpio71-RX. gpio71 is configured as an input and is ready to receive data:
debian@beaglebone:~/bbg$ cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio71/direction /sys/class/gpio/gpio71/value
in
1

I've made the physical connection between PC_10 (UART-TX) on the Nucleo and gpio71 on the BeagleBone Green. However, the BeagleBone Green isn't receiving the "Hello World!" message. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.
Can anyone help me figure out how to successfully receive data on the BeagleBone Green from the Nucleo F746ZG?
Thx!

updated
    /*
      Pin PC_10 is configured as UART-TX (port CN8)
     */
    char msg[15] = "Hello World!";

    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1)
    {
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < strlen(msg); ++i) {
            status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, (uint8_t*) (msg + i), 1, 1000);
            if (status != HAL_OK) {
                printf("UART_Receive failed with status: %d\r\n", status);
                printf("[err] could not transmit Uart tx\r\n");
            }
        }

        printf("\r\n");
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */   


Code on BBG for testing, it works correctly.
$ cat uart.hpp

#ifndef UART_H
#define UART_H

#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

class uart
{
    public:
        enum BaudRate
        {
            BAUD_2400 = B2400,
            BAUD_9600 = B9600,
            BAUD_19200 = B19200,
            BAUD_38400 = B38400,
            BAUD_57600 = B57600
        };

        uart(std::string path, BaudRate BaudRate, char parity, uint32_t databits, uint32_t stopbits,
                uint32_t vmin, uint32_t timeout);
        ~uart();

        bool isOpen();
        ssize_t writeData(const std::string& buff);
        ssize_t readData(std::string &buff, uint32_t sizeRead);

        // GPIO methods
        bool setupGPIO(int pin, const std::string& direction);
        bool readGPIO(int pin, int &value);
        bool writeGPIO(int pin, int value);

    private:
        BaudRate m_baudRate;
        char m_parity;
        uint32_t m_databits;
        uint32_t m_stopbits;
        uint32_t m_vmin;
        struct termios m_uart;

        uint32_t m_timeout;

        int m_fd;
        bool m_isOpen;

        bool openDevice(const std::string& path);
        bool closeDevice();
        bool initDevice();

        std::string gpioPath(int pin);
};

#endif



$ cat uart.cpp

#include "uart.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

uart::uart(std::string path, BaudRate BaudRate, char parity, uint32_t databits, uint32_t stopbits,
        uint32_t vmin, uint32_t timeout)
{
    m_baudRate = BaudRate;
    m_parity = parity;
    m_databits = databits;
    m_stopbits = stopbits;
    m_vmin = vmin;
    m_timeout = timeout;

    m_fd = -1;
    m_isOpen = false;

    if (!openDevice(path))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open port");
    }

    m_isOpen = true;

    if (!initDevice())
    {
        closeDevice();
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize uart");
    }
}

uart::~uart()
{
    closeDevice();
}

bool uart::isOpen()
{
    return m_isOpen;
}

ssize_t uart::writeData(const std::string& buff)
{
    return write(m_fd, buff.c_str(), buff.length());
}

ssize_t uart::readData(std::string &buff, uint32_t sizeRead)
{
    buff.resize(sizeRead);
    return read(m_fd, &buff[0], sizeRead);
}

bool uart::openDevice(const std::string& path)
{
    m_fd = open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (m_fd == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    m_isOpen = true;
    return true;
}

bool uart::closeDevice()
{
    if (isOpen() && close(m_fd) == 0)
    {
        m_isOpen = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool uart::initDevice()
{
    if (tcgetattr(m_fd, &m_uart))
    {
        return false;
    }

    cfsetispeed(&m_uart, m_baudRate);
    cfsetospeed(&m_uart, m_baudRate);

    m_uart.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     // Clear parity enable
    m_uart.c_cflag &= ~CSTOP;      // Clear stop bits
    m_uart.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;      // Clear character size bits

    m_uart.c_iflag = IGNBRK;       // 
    m_uart.c_lflag = 0;            // 
    m_uart.c_oflag = 0;            // 

    m_uart.c_cflag |= ~PARENB;     // Set parity bits
    m_uart.c_cflag |= ~CSTOP;      // Set stop bits
    m_uart.c_cflag |= ~CSIZE;      // Set data bits

    m_uart.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

    m_uart.c_cc[VTIME] = m_timeout;
    m_uart.c_cc[VMIN] = m_vmin;

    m_uart.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    if (tcsetattr(m_fd, TCSANOW, &m_uart))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool uart::setupGPIO(int pin, const std::string& direction)
{
    std::string path = gpioPath(pin) + "/direction";
    std::ofstream gpio_dir(path);
    if (!gpio_dir.is_open())
        return false;
    gpio_dir << direction;
    gpio_dir.close();
    return true;
}

bool uart::readGPIO(int pin, int &value)
{
    std::string path = gpioPath(pin) + "/value";
    std::ifstream gpio_value(path);
    if (!gpio_value.is_open())
        return false;
    gpio_value >> value;
    gpio_value.close();
    return true;
}

bool uart::writeGPIO(int pin, int value)
{
    std::string path = gpioPath(pin) + "/value";
    std::ofstream gpio_value(path);
    if (!gpio_value.is_open())
        return false;
    gpio_value << value;
    gpio_value.close();
    return true;
}

std::string uart::gpioPath(int pin)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "/sys/class/gpio/gpio" << pin;
    return ss.str();
}



$ cat main.cpp

#include "uart.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // uart initialize
        uart my_uart("/dev/ttyS1", uart::BAUD_9600, 'N', 8, 1, 1, 1);
        std::cout << "UART initialized successfully!" << std::endl;

        // settings
        // For transmit:
        // /sys/class/gpio/gpio72/direction /sys/class/gpio/gpio72/value
        // direction need to configure to: out
        // the value need to configure to: 1
        //
        // For receive:
        // /sys/class/gpio/gpio71/direction /sys/class/gpio/gpio71/value
        // direction need to configure to: in
        // the value need to configure to: 0
        //                                 ^
        //                                 |
        //                    when the connection closed between pinouts the value
        //                    the main.c change it to 1


        // setting gpio
        my_uart.setupGPIO(71, "in");
        my_uart.setupGPIO(72, "out");

        std::cout << "GPIO 71 set to input mode." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GPIO 72 set to output mode." << std::endl;

        // data that I want to send
        std::string message = "Hello, World!";
        while (true)
        {
            int value;
            if (my_uart.readGPIO(71, value))
            {
                std::cout << "GPIO 71 value read: " << value << std::endl;
                if (value == 1)
                {
                    std::cout << "GPIO is high. Sending message: " << message << std::endl;
                    ssize_t bytesWritten =  my_uart.writeData(message);
                    std::cout << "Bytes sent: " << bytesWritten << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "Failed to read GPIO 71 value." << std::endl;
            }

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        }

    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}



Looks like you are programming in C++, since the C language doesn't have std::cout.  I don't recommend mixing the two languages, since C++ has features like function and operator overloading, which complicate the mixing of C and C++ by the linker.  You should remove the C language tag.

So what is huart5 for? It's not very clear what the problem is here. Maybe spend some time making a simpler example. Pretend that we have no idea what your system is like... because we don't...and go from there.

Why the weird 100ms delay between sending each character from the STM32, and receiving one back? Why does it have to be lockstep like that. This is some very weird code. Your code seems misguided in a way that I can't easily explain in a comment. But I don't know what your code is actually meant to do.

Do your boards share a common GND? If not, none of this will work. Connect GND on the STM32 to GND on the BeagleBoard.

Where's the code for BB procedures my_uart(), setupGPIO(), readGPIO(), and readData()? Why is a GPIO checked before reading the serial terminal? Have you created a new interface? "I've made the physical connection between PC_10 (UART-TX) on the Nucleo and gpio71 on the BeagleBone Green" - We need to see a complete connection diagram, rather than a word description. FYI a GPIO pin cannot "receive" UART data unless you have code to bit-bang receive it.

@ThomasMatthews - The STM32 board seems to be baremetal and C. It's the BB Green that's Linux and C++. So the c language tag is appropriate for  half of the problem.

"Both code snippets work independently" Please explain how you have verified that.

@ThomasMatthews The C++ is just for example but I'm going to rewrite it in C.

@pmacfarlane You are right that huart5 is not needed if I am transmitting only on BBG, these are the test cases that I did on f746zg.

@pmacfarlane Delay of 100 ms is different variants of tests that I tried to do. Since on f746zg BaudRate 115200, and BBG if I am not mistake does not support such speed, I decided to make different variants of delays and I also change the BaudRate huart4.Init.BaudRate = 9600;on f746zg same as on the BBG.
My BBG code that I'm trying to write should receive the data that transmited from F746ZG, in my example i try to get the msg[15] = "Hello World!"

@pmacfarlane Yes, I do the connection of GND on the STM32 to GND on the BeagleBoard.

@sawdust Transmite and Receive on BBG works without problem. I have trouble when I try send data from f746zg to bbg. Thanks

I need to transimt the msg from f746zg by the &uart4 to gpio71 on the bbg. The gpio71 configured to:
/sys/class/gpio/gpio71/direction --> in and
/sys/class/gpio/gpio71/value      --> 1

"Transmite and Receive on BBG works without problem" - That's hard to believe. The termios initialization in uart::initDevice() is broken. Statements such as m_uart.c_iflag = IGNBRK;  are bad practice; see Setting Terminal Modes Properly. But statements such as m_uart.c_cflag |= ~PARENB;  are bugs that clobber previous settings such as the baudrate. Maybe a loopback works, but not a real serial connection. You still need to explain how things are connected, and how/what you expect to read from a GPIO pin.

"I need to transimt the msg from f746zg by the &uart4 to gpio71 on the bbg" - When you transmit using a UART, then you need to receive with another UART. You do not try to use a GPIO pin for "receiving" unless you're playing around with bit-banging.

Does UART require both Tx and Rx to be connected?
